# Shell command syntax, input array of args for single option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is something I have seen many times in manuals, but never fully understood the syntax. When an argument is allowed to be an array of multiple values, what exactly does this syntax mean and how is it used to specify multiple args for the single flag/option?

```
command_name -f par_name=par_value[,par_name=par_value...]
```

Another common way I've seen this presented is:

```
usage: command_name [-f variable_list]
```

What is an example of this usage in practice? I have been trying with and without commas and brackets but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Nothing about this is related to bash -- the syntax available for commands started from a shell is completely agnostic of the shell in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usage: command_name [-f variable_list]
```

This means that both `command_name` and `command_name -f variable_list` are valid

```
command_name -f par_name=par_value[,par_name=par_value...]
```

This means that:

`command_name -f par_name=par_value` and

`command_name -f par_name=par_value,par_name=par_value` and

`command_name -f par_name=par_value,par_name=par_value,par_name=par_value`

etc. are all valid.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed. Mainly that there are no spaces between the arguments and commas, that threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

```
command_name -f par_name=par_value[,par_name=par_value...]
```

The brackets here actually means that these options are optional. You don't add the bracket `[]` when you actually add these options.

So you can omit the extra options like :

```
command_name -f par_name=par_value
```

Or use it:

```
command_name -f par_name=par_value,par_name=par_value
```

or even more.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an array, that is a kind of extended [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) where arguments in square brakets are optionals, ones in curly braces are repetible and so on.

So for example for your second example you can execute

```
command_name
```

or

```
command_name -f variable_list
```